# Optimalization of recursive function

Tags: scala, performance, functional-programming

I'm trying to solve [Messy Medians](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/messy-medians/problem) problem for functional programming on hackerrank.

My solution (below) is too slow. It timeouts almost half of testcases.

```
@tailrec
def calculate(steps: List[Int], states: List[List[Int]]): List[Int] = {

  steps match {
    case x::xs =>
      if(x > 0) {
        states match { //apend state
          case Nil => calculate(xs, List(x) :: states)
          case y :: _ => calculate(xs, (x :: y) :: states)
        }
      } else {
        calculate(xs, states.drop(-x-1).head :: states) //rollback state
      }
    case Nil => states
      .reverse
      .map { // calculate median
        case List(x) => x
        case xs => xs.sorted.apply(if (xs.length % 2 != 0) xs.length/2 else xs.length/2 - 1)
      }
  }
}
```

How can I optimize it? There could be up to 100000 input states.
When I used `TreeSet` instead of `List` for state it started working faster, but then it stopped working for cases, when there are duplicate numbers. 
Is there something in scala as sorted list?

Comment: For what it's worth, my most recent attempt to solve this passes all tests except one (#9 always times out). I got this close only after realizing that a big penalty was incurred when copying all the data in order to keep a status record of every step along the way. Not every `step` needs to save its `state`.

Comment: Can you share your solution as answer :) ?  I'm still struggling with it. Instead of calculating median at the end, I tried with running median, but still 4 test cases time out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I didn't read the algorithm (or the problem), so, I can't speak to correctness of your solution, but here are a few problems I spotted with the code:

- result of `xs.sorted.length` is the same as that of `xs.length`, that sort is just a waste.
- `List.apply` is linear time. If you want random access by index, use `IndexedSeq` instead of `List`
- `List.length` is also linear. If you are switching to `IndexedSeq`, this is inconsequential, but you should keep it in mind for the future. In the very least,never do `xs.length` multiple times, when you can do it once, and save the result in a variable. But even then, it's still linear. It is better to just pass the length around, rather than computing it every time.
- You may also want to consider using [quickselect algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect) for finding a median in O(logN) time.
- `if(n % 2 != 0) n/2 else n/2 - 1` is the same thing as `(n-1)/2` ... not that it would effect your performance (once you fix the `.length` thingy), but just looks weird.  You also don't need a special case for `List(x)` there. Just `{ xs => xs((xs.length-1)/2) }` would do.

Comment: Also no need to `reverse` before taking the median :)

Comment: For sorted, it was just mistake :) I was doing some changes in code and I copied wrong version here. Correct version is in updated question. I needed to sort before taking median, because I need element from the middle of sorted collection. @Tim I need reverse because medians would be in wrong order.

Comment: You may also consider using `quick-select` algorithm for picking the median